# Send media file (image,audio,video) using xmpp ios

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, openfire, file-transfer

Hi i am creating a chat app using xmpp, openfire. Now chat(text message) working fine for media i use transfer file demo of xmpp but it only work if both user are online. So pls help me to send file to offline user

Comment: We need to see some code in order to help you with it. We can't predict how u'r code is looking now.

Answer (score 0):

Chat apps only work if both users are online. If you want to transfer a file to someone who is not on-line, send e-mail. Or, copy to the file to a file sharing service and send them a text message with the URL where you stored the file.

xmpp media transfer is peer to peer, with a server managing the rendezvous, the server does not participate in the transfer of data between the endpoints, so the server can't buffer anything like a file transfer.

Comment: can we use server to save media get back url from server and send that url in xmpp body message.